# How would we attract Selenium users to ask question on SQA site than on StackOveflow?

Tags: discussion, support

As we all know area51 selenium proposal was merged in to SQA forum.
And there are already selenium tags on StackOveflow. 
Challenge would be to have Selenium questions coming to SQA site. So -

1. Will StackOverflow notify Selenium users about SQA site when they posts selenium qs on StackOverflow? If not then how would be we get Selenium users posting there questions here so that there is one place of qa/sqa needs?
2. What happens to existing Selenium qs at StackOverflow site? Will those questions be migrated to SQA site? If yes then how and who would be carrying out this exercise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. I expect that this will be done the same way it is now for questions on topics such as Ubuntu and Apple (and Unix, and WordPress, etc.). The community will see the question, and people will either flag it as something to be moved or add a comment suggesting that the user instead ask it at a different site.

   So far, there's never been a need for Stack Exchange staff to actively do anything—the community has done a great job of handling it on their own.
2. Up to now we haven't done this without a really darn good reason. Messing with Google's incoming links is almost always a bad idea, and in general, people expect to be able to find their questions where they last saw them.

The default for this site is to handle questions like this in the same way we've handled them on other offshoot sites.

Answer (score 4):

Folks will flag the posts to be moved, but that cannot happen until the private beta is passed.