# What's the most appropriate stack-exchange site to post my selenium autotest coding questions?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, meta

Hi,

I was wondering whether I should be posting questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103134/selenium-2-c-webdriver-why-cant-i-move-from-one-input-to-another-in-ie8) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050270/c-webdriver-how-do-i-discover-an-xpath-from-a-known-element-classname), on [SQA](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/), or on [StackOverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com/) where I originally put them?

The reason I ask, is because I see a lot of tech type questions on SQA, but also many manual qa questions, as well as questions like I've often seen on [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Thanks in advance for your patience, if this question has already been asked.

Comment: b/w have you seen this proposal - http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/31757/browser-automation One more attempt from Selenium community and we hope it gets through this time atleast

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like many of the StackExchange sites, there is considerable overlap in the covered topics of SQA. As you mentioned, the technical side overlaps on to StackOverflow, while the procedural side overlaps onto Programmers. This is very much intentional, as it brings together the important element that the two are related, even though each site will bounce the offending questions to the other.

So to answer your question, you can post technical QA questions here or on StackOverflow. You can post procedural QA questions here or on Programmers. Just don't post technical questions on Programmers (they'll send you to SO, or maybe here) procedural questions on StackOverflow (They'll send you to P.se or here) or non-QA questions here (we'll send you to SO or P.se, or cars.SE if that's where the question belongs!)

Using SQA instead of SO/P.se
 * Users are more dedicated to SQA, increasing probability of a directed answer
 * Because it bridges the gap between procedural and technical topics, you're more likely to get a balanced answer here than on either of the others.

Cons to using SQA
 * A smaller userbase/contentbase means longer delays in getting the answer
 * Lack of community-decided standards have potential to cause some problems getting the answers you seek

The good news is that the cons are temporary and are relative to the age of the site. Indeed, each site on the StackExchange network (and every site EVER) has gone through these growing pains.

I would welcome any question you have on SQA that would have had one of the following tags on SO/P.se - that doesn't mean they aren't just as appropriate as they were before on the original site, this just means they are also welcome here.
 * Selenium
 * Selenium2
 * QA
 * testing
 * test-automation

That's just off the top of my head, I'm sure there's plenty of other tags that would qualify on that list.

**tl;dr** - The existence of this site does not make questions any more or less appropriate on their original sites. It merely provides an alternative venue which, over time, will likely be the send-point for questions of QA nature on the original sites.

Answer (score 2):

Well as you might know that Selenium proposal was merged in to SQA proposal, despite all the [ranting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88952/how-do-i-reopen-a-closed-proposal) we did. Many of the Selenium Committer decided to uncommit from SQA proposal after the merge though I continued to be a committer despite having drawn [differences](https://sqa.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82/is-it-wrong-to-publicize-the-sqa-site-on-stack-exchange) with other committers :-(. I love both Selenium and Stack Exchange and not ready to give up any.

Coming back to your question, I assume SQA should be the place to post Selenium Question and if not then what was the whole objective of merging Selenium Proposal to SQA proposal? 
I hang out here more often than on StackOverflow and could try to answer your questions and that's only I could say.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there are still plenty of people in SQA who use Selenium, I do, although I never agreed with the rationale to the merge I do have an interest in SQA which overlaps with Selenium.  There are others so if you post here you will probably get a different take on the question than on StackOverflow, due to the difference in populations.